# OS error 87 "The parameter is incorrect." on std::fs::OpenOptions

Tags: windows, rust

`std::fs::OpenOptions` `.open()` is working fine until I downloaded a crate [directories](https://crates.io/crates/directories)
. I've tried removing the .toml dependencies and changing project but still receiving the same error using `OpenOptions`. Using `std::fs::File` `.create()` `.open()` seems to works just fine.

This is the output: `Err(Os { code: 87, kind: InvalidInput, message: "The parameter is incorrect." })`

The exact code used for testing in new project.

```
fn main() {
    let r = std::fs::OpenOptions::new()
        .create_new(true)
        .open("foo.txt");
    println!("What is this bug: {:?}", r);
}
```

Rust version 1.59.0

Comment: this seems very specific to your pc, error usually happens because of some antivirus activity of deprecated drivers

Comment: getting the same issue.

Comment: I've tested this on my another computer and getting the same error. This is likely not pc specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The file must be opened with write or append access in order to create
> a new file. -- [create_new docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.OpenOptions.html#method.create_new)

This works:

```
fn main() {
    let r = std::fs::OpenOptions::new()
        .create_new(true).write(true)
        .open("foo.txt");
    println!("What is this bug: {:?}", r);
}
```